# Cloudflare file caches won’t be cleared even in ‘ON’ Development mode in DNS

Tags: caching, dns, cloudflare

I use Cloudflare as a DNS server for my website.
for example, I defined [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com), landing.mydomain.com to point to a Google Cloud CDN storage bucket IP in which I serve my static landing files.
the problem is when I deploy a new version of my code on that bucket, even after time passes more than the cache TTL of that bucket, I see my old landing on my domains, specifically on my www subdomain.
when I use another DNS server like DNSimple, the problem resolves.
I think the problem is with the Cloudflare caching system.
I went to the Caching part of my domain’s configurations in the Cloudflare panel, purged entire caches, and set the Development mode “ON” and also set the “Always Online” part “OFF”.
but the problem remains.
I’d be very delighted If anybody could tell me what should I do to get rid of the cache!

Comment: can you add what the CF-Cache-Status header indicates for these static files?